# Is there a way to prevent the post viewed by the visitor?

Tags: php

Supposed the page is `example.com/blog/data.php`. I am using `file_get_contents` to get the content in another script page. Now, i want to:

1. Forbid google search to crawl and index the data.php page.
2. Forbid the visitor to access it

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect to another page if the request url is `example.com/blog/data.php`, but a far easier and more logical solution would be to move the file out of your web-root.

**Edit:** If you really want to keep the file inside the web-root, you can use something like this at the top of the script that you don't want to access directly:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])
{
  header('Location: /');    // redirect to home page
}
```

However, this will probably not work in combination with `file_get_contents` (you need to remove these lines from the result), you could `include` the file instead.

Comment: how to  redirect to another page in example.com/blog/data.php?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `data.php` under the web root. Keep it in a parallel directory.

Comment: how to forbid google search to crawl and index the data.php page.

Comment: You do what it says in the answer. If it isn't under the web root, it doesn't have a URL. If it doesn't have a URL then Google can't crawl it.

Comment: if there is no a url, how to use file_get_contents to get the page content?

Comment: your meaning is put data.php into public_html in my host. then  file_get_contents('data.php').am i right?

Comment: No. **outside** public_html. Then `file_get_contents("../../private/data.php")`

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply access restriction for authorized users only. You are able to do it in the most simple way by accessing your page using url parama as password:

example.com/blog/data.php?secret=someblah

and in the first of your file data.php do the following:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['secret']) || $_GET['secret'] != 'someblah')) exit();
?>
```

However,It is recommended, don't use this from public computer becuase it is not secure but it is the primitive authentication principle.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass token via GET. Overall your way is slightly wrong. Why don't you incorporate the data.php logic in the script that is calling it.